# confused by `no space left on device` exception

Tags: docker, containers

I came across an exception

```
openj9-openjdk-jdk9/.git/HEAD
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /root/openj9-openjdk-jdk9/.git/objects/pack/pack-203ba520304c417be0828d545d85ffd13566ac41.pack: no space left on device
```

and a popup diagram said '/root' is only 672M available, when executing command:

```
docker build -t openj9 -f Dockerfile .
```

The Dockerfile is

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends \
    autoconf \
    ca-certificates \
    ccache \
    cpio \
    file \
    g++-4.8 \
    gcc-4.8 \
    git \
    git-core \
    libasound2-dev \
    libcups2-dev \
    libelf-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libnuma-dev \
    libx11-dev \
    libxext-dev \
    libxrender-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libxtst-dev \
    make \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    pkg-config \
    realpath \
    ssh \
    unzip \
    wget \
    zip \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY openj9-openjdk-jdk9.tar.gz    /root/
COPY  freemarker.tgz  /root/
# Create links for c++,g++,cc,gcc
RUN ln -s g++ /usr/bin/c++ \
  && ln -s g++-4.8 /usr/bin/g++ \
  && ln -s gcc /usr/bin/cc \
  && ln -s gcc-4.8 /usr/bin/gcc

# Download and setup freemarker.jar to /root/freemarker.jar
RUN cd /root \
#  && wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/freemarker/files/freemarker/2.3.8/freemarker-2.3.8.tar.gz/download -O freemarker.tgz \
  && tar -xzf freemarker.tgz freemarker-2.3.8/lib/freemarker.jar --strip=2 \
  && rm -f freemarker.tgz \
  && tar xvf openj9-openjdk-jdk9.tar.gz \
  && rm -f openj9-openjdk-jdk9.tar.gz

WORKDIR /root
```

The error happens when executing `tar xvf openj9-openjdk-jdk9.tar.gz`.

What confuse me is that the partition where the directory `/root` resides still has a large space i.e., 4.3G, as shown below.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           778M   78M  701M  10% /run
/dev/sda1        32G   27G  4.3G  86% /
tmpfs           3.8G  113M  3.7G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop1       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6818
/dev/loop2      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/webdingding/1
/dev/loop3       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6531
/dev/loop4      254M  254M     0 100% /snap/electronic-wechat/7
/dev/sda6        31G  1.1G   29G   4% /opt
/dev/sda5        38G   25G   11G  71% /home
/dev/sdb7        52G   25G   25G  50% /home_bak
/dev/sdb5        37G   28G  7.4G  79% /backup
/dev/sdb8        81G   68G  8.8G  89% /opt1
/dev/sdb6        97G   72G   20G  79% /other
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           778M  172K  778M   1% /run/user/1000
```

So, my two main questions are:

1. How to understand the path in the container? Is the container path `/root` is the same as the absolute path `/root` in the host machine, or is it mapped to some other paths in the host machine?
2. The solution for the problem. I tried [this one](https://success.docker.com/article/no-space-left-on-device-error), but failed. As the container log file was very small

   root@shijie:~# du -d1 -h /var/lib/docker/containers

   ```
   40K /var/lib/docker/containers/f41f43b5a4372dda5e2aba71c3ae8cc58170b2f13183e22942fa62747910ac7a
   44K /var/lib/docker/containers
   ```

---

**[Update]**
I also cleared the `containers` and `images`, and then re-execute the command, and the result is the same.

`sudo docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
f41f43b5a437        b68439663072        "/bin/sh -c 'cd /roo…"   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                       brave_albattani
```

`sudo docker rm f41f43b5a437`
`sudo docker images`

```
   REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
    <none>              <none>              b68439663072        2 hours ago         1.66GB
    ubuntu              16.04               a3551444fc85        2 weeks ago         119MB
```

`sudo docker rmi b68439663072 a3551444fc85`

`sudo docker images -aq -f 'dangling=true'`    ## No dangling images..

[image: popup diagram]

Comment: 1. `$ docker images -aq -f 'dangling=true' | xargs docker rmi1` and 2.`$ docker volume ls -q -f 'dangling=true' | xargs docker volume rm`  **WARNING: Take care with this command, as it will remove all dangling volumes whether they are anonymous or named.**

Comment: Try the above commands. Sometimes this happens because of junk and dangling images we present in machine and Volumes we with containers.

Comment: @Akshaybarahate Thanks. Yet, there is no dangling images as I had repeated the build instruction after clearly them. See my `Update` above. Other ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/blob/master/buildenv/docker/jdk8/x86_64/ubuntu16/Dockerfile#L20 can you try this file . I see some error while executing your docker file.   **tar File size is bothering me and copy process**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By default, Docker store everything in `/var/lib/docker` so every path in your container is absolute **inside your container** but relative to you docker root path (ie : `/var/lib/docker/containers`)
2. In order to know the resource used by Docker, you can execute this command `docker system df`. In order to clean everything that is not currently used by docker you can execute this command `docker system prune`. Otherwise you can just specify which resource you want to clean (for example `docker container prune`).

Comment: After `docker system prune`, I re-execute the command but still fail with the same error message. So is it owning to my `/dev/sda1` with 4G avail is too small, and change the default docker store location?

Comment: No, in my opinion, if your image is ~4G then there is something wrong with it.
What's bothering me is your error message `openj9-openjdk-jdk9/.git/HEAD` : how come there is a `.git` folder in your jdk archive ?
Also what is the size of this archive when it's extracted in your local disk ?

Comment: It is total 3.5G after unzip. and there is .git directory inside openj9-openjdk-jdk9 as the zip file `openj9-openjdk-jdk9` contains source for compilation

Comment: So you have your answer. It seems really weird that your openjdk is 3.5G !!
Either way, you don't have a lot of choice here : either you change your Docker root path (wich is not recommended), or you resolve the size problem of your openjdk file. You can probably get a new base image that already has openjdk9 installed (and that is not 3.5G!).

Comment: Thanks all . The `Dockerfile` is old version. I solved the space and would be try new version. Thanks.  @Akshaybarahate Using a zip because the connection to github here is slow.